# How to menu on one line and always in center?

Tags: css, menu

I have a menu that I want to always be in the top-center of the screen. I want the menu to always look the same and be on one line independent on the screen width (I will make it disappear at a certain width). At the moment the menu becomes a two-line-menu at a certain width for some reason.

How do I remove this two-line-menu problem?

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b91whh0a/)**

Resize the screen in the jsfiddle and you will understand what I mean.

**HTML**:

```
<ul id="menu">
  <li><a href="#" class="menu-items1">OM OSS</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="menu-items1">TJÄNSTER</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="menu-items1">KUNDER</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="menu-items1">ADDRESS</a></li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**:

```
ul {
    list-style-type:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    position: absolute;
    margin-left:29%;
    margin-right:29vw;
}

li {
    display:inline-block;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 1px;
}

li a {
    font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
    font-size: 11px;
    letter-spacing:2px;
    display:block;
    height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 50px;
    color: #000;
}

.menu-items1 {
    min-width:90px;
    margin-top:1.5px;
}

.menu-items2-1 {
    margin-left:20px;
}

.menu-items2-2 {
    margin-left:20px;
    margin-top:0.5px;
}

.menu-items2-3 {
    margin-left:10px;
}

.menu-items2-4 {
    margin-left:30px;
    margin-top:0.5px;
}

li:hover a {
    text-decoration:none;
  color: rgba(153, 153, 153, 1);
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s;
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
  cursor: pointer;
}

li ul li a {
    width: auto;
    min-width: 100px;
    padding: 0 20px;
}
```

Comment: What do you want to happen when the screen width is too small to show them on one line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've re-structured your HTML/CSS a bit. Pay close attention to 4 and 5 below but, in summary, I...

1. Changed the CSS hooks to be mostly classes (less dependency on markup in selectors)
2. Added an HTML5 tag, `<nav>`, to the markup for better semantics
3. Removed the `<a>` tag for one of the menu items to show why I moved the class to the `<li>` and moved some of the CSS properties to different rules
4. Added `white-space: nowrap;` to keep inline-block elements on one line
5. Added breakpoint at 480px (via media query) to re-format menu when the screen is too small

```css
.menu-list {
  display: block;
  padding: 0px;
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.menu-list-item {
  display: block;
  min-width: 90px;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  font-size: 11px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
  color: #000;
}

.menu-list-item a {
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.menu-list-item:hover a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: rgba(153, 153, 153, 1);
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s;
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
}

@media(min-width: 480px) {
  .menu-list-item { display: inline-block; }
  .menu-list-item a { min-width: 90px; }
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul class="menu-list">
    <li class="menu-list-item"><a href="#">OM OSS</a></li>
    <li class="menu-list-item"><a href="#">TJÄNSTER</a></li>
    <li class="menu-list-item"><a href="#">KUNDER</a></li>
    <li class="menu-list-item">ADDRESS</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

[JSFiddle version](https://jsfiddle.net/pnk7zhsz/1/)

Answer (score 1):

In order to always keep them in one line, you could use table display:

```
#menu {
    display: table;
}
.menu-items {
    display: table-cell;
}
```

Here is your example updated: https://jsfiddle.net/25brdx7r/

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using margin percentages to center your text, you can use `text-align: center;`

1. Remove the `margin-left` and `margin-right` from you `ul`.
2. Add `width: 100%;`, `text-align: center;` and `white-space: nowrap;` to your `ul`.
3. Remove `float: left;` from your `li` styles.

```css
html, body {
    width: 100%; height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

/*Strip the ul of padding and list styling*/
ul {
 list-style-type:none;
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 position: absolute;
 width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
        white-space: nowrap;
}

/*Create a horizontal list with spacing*/
li {
 display:inline-block;
 margin-right: 1px;
}

/*Style for menu links*/
li a {
 font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
    font-size: 11px;
    letter-spacing:2px;
 display:block;
 height: 50px;
 text-align: center;
 line-height: 50px;
 color: #000;
}

.menu-items1 {
 min-width:90px;
 margin-top:1.5px;
}

.menu-items2-1 {
 margin-left:20px;
}

.menu-items2-2 {
 margin-left:20px;
 margin-top:0.5px;
}

.menu-items2-3 {
 margin-left:10px;
}

.menu-items2-4 {
 margin-left:30px;
 margin-top:0.5px;
}

/*Hover state for top level links*/
li:hover a {
 text-decoration:none;
  color: rgba(153, 153, 153, 1);
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s;
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/*Prevent text wrapping*/
li ul li a {
 width: auto;
 min-width: 100px;
 padding: 0 20px;
}
```

```html
<ul id="menu">
  <li><a href="#" class="menu-items1">OM OSS</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="menu-items1">TJÄNSTER</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="menu-items1">KUNDER</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="menu-items1">ADDRESS</a></li>
</ul>
```

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b91whh0a/5/)**

Comment: Found a solution with the help of your answer, thanx :)

Answer (score 0):

Change your display to inline. Block displays on another line.